# JQuery not resizing div on window resize

Tags: javascript, jquery, resize

So I have a JQuery function that is built to make column heights the same. It checks the screen size, and if it's on a medium sized device or bigger, it will resize the column to the same heights. This part of the function works great. However, if it gets resized to mobile size (or anything under 1025px) the height does not reset to the original size and stays at the increased size. If it starts on a small screen, it will appear correctly until it is resized to a large screen and then resized to a small screen again (then the same problem as above occurs).

Here is the code!

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
        matchColHeight('.intro-pic', '.intro-desc-container');

        $(window).resize(function(){
            matchColHeight('.intro-pic', '.intro-desc-container');
        });
    }); 

    function matchColHeight(tallColumn, shortColumn){
        shortOriginalHeight = $(shortColumn).height();

        if (window.matchMedia('(min-width: 1025px)').matches) { 
            height = $(tallColumn).height();
            $(shortColumn).css({
                'height': height + 'px'
            });
        }
        else{
            $(shortColumn).css({
                'height': shortOriginalHeight + 'px'
            });
        }
    }
```

**Note:** I've also tried using the below function and it had the same issues:

```
    function matchColHeight(tallColumn, shortColumn){
        shortOriginalHeight = $(shortColumn).height();
        screenSize = $(window).width();

        if (screenSize > 1025){     
            height = $(tallColumn).height();
            $(shortColumn).css({
                'height': height + 'px'
            });
        }
        else{
            $(shortColumn).css({
                'height': shortOriginalHeight + 'px'
            });
        }
    }
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: why don't u use mediaquery in css rather than this

Comment: @Çağrı I'm using the Zurb Foundation framework. Sadly, the only way (as far as I'm aware of) to make columns the same height based on the content inside them is with JavaScript.

Comment: I see,  $(window).width(); is this working or not ? if not working maybe in meta tag device width is missing.

Comment: @Çağrı `$(window).width();` is working properly; It alerts the proper window size on resize.

Comment: @Enrico Ah. I think I see the problem now. OriginalHeight will redefine itself each on resize. Looks like a logic error on my end :(

Comment: That's because the shortcolumn variable gets updated in the if statement. When you switch to mobile size, it actually does nothing more than applying the same height as before

Comment: looks like adding `$(shortColumn).removeAttr( 'style' );` appeared to do the trick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up resolving my issue by changing the function to the following:

```
function matchColHeight(tallColumn, shortColumn){
    if (window.matchMedia('(min-width: 40em)').matches) {   
    height = $(tallColumn).height();
    $(shortColumn).css({
        'height': height + 'px'
        });
    }
    else{
        $(shortColumn).removeAttr('style');
    }
}
```

Instead of storing the original height and reverting back to it, I just removed the modified height when it isn't needed.